# Tree Question - [Most efficient solution]

Tags: javascript, tree

Im trying to get the most efficient way to walk the following tree. If i get everything under the parent 'C' it should be ['c', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'g'].

My current solution is the following, however i know its not the most effiecent way of solving the issue but cant think how to do it in a more efficient way.

```js
var t0 = performance.now()

const data = [
    { id: 'a', name: 'a', parentId: '' },
    { id: 'b', name: 'b', parentId: 'c' },
    { id: 'c', name: 'c', parentId: '' },
    { id: 'd', name: 'd', parentId: 'c' },
    { id: 'e', name: 'e', parentId: 'd' },
    { id: 'f', name: 'f', parentId: 'a' },
    { id: 'g', name: 'g', parentId: 'e' }
];

function walk(companyId = 'c') {

  const final = new Set()

  function walkLevel(id) {

    data.filter(line => line.parentId === id || line.id === id)
      .map((line) => {
          if(line.id === id) {
            final.add(line)
          } else {
            return line
          }
      })
      .filter((o) => !!o)
      .forEach((level) => {
        walkLevel(level.id)
      })

  }

  walkLevel(companyId)

  return [...final]

}

var t1 = performance.now()

console.log(walk('c'))

console.log("Call took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")
```

Comment: What kind of size and depth are you looking at for the actual data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breadth-first walks are usually done without recursion, with a queue of nodes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search for details.

```js
data = [
    {id: 'a', name: 'a', parentId: ''},
    {id: 'b', name: 'b', parentId: 'c'},
    {id: 'c', name: 'c', parentId: ''},
    {id: 'd', name: 'd', parentId: 'c'},
    {id: 'e', name: 'e', parentId: 'd'},
    {id: 'f', name: 'f', parentId: 'a'},
    {id: 'g', name: 'g', parentId: 'e'}
]

function bfs(id = 'c') {

    let queue = data.filter(d => d.id === id)
    let res = []

    while (queue.length) {
        let o = queue.shift()
        res.push(o)
        queue.push(...data.filter(d => d.parentId === o.id))
    }

    return res
}

console.log(bfs())
```

For very large trees you can optimize this by precomputing an adjacency list `parentId=>objects` thus avoiding repeated `filter` calls:

```js
data = [
    {id: 'a', name: 'a', parentId: ''},
    {id: 'b', name: 'b', parentId: 'c'},
    {id: 'c', name: 'c', parentId: ''},
    {id: 'd', name: 'd', parentId: 'c'},
    {id: 'e', name: 'e', parentId: 'd'},
    {id: 'f', name: 'f', parentId: 'a'},
    {id: 'g', name: 'g', parentId: 'e'}
]

function adjList(data) {
    let m = new Map

    for (let o of data) {
        if (!m.has(o.parentId))
            m.set(o.parentId, [])
        m.get(o.parentId).push(o)
    }

    return m
}

function bfs(id = 'c') {

    let adj = adjList(data)
    let queue = data.filter(d => d.id === id)
    let res = []

    while (queue.length) {
        let o = queue.shift()
        res.push(o)
        if (adj.has(o.id))
            queue.push(...adj.get(o.id)) // O(1)
    }

    return res
}

console.log(bfs())
```

Whether this optimization actually makes sense should be considered carefully, because creating a map is not free. For example, libraries like lodash usually have a threshold value (~200 elements) and do not preoptimize if the input is smaller than that.

Comment: Thanks for this i think i understand whats happening in your examples. Are u able to add performance metrics to these? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how efficient this is (it may be dependent on your data) but I think that it can sometimes be worth mapping by id or parent id first especially if you need to do it several times, as you can reuse the map.

```js
const data = [
    { id: 'a', name: 'a', parentId: '' },
    { id: 'b', name: 'b', parentId: 'c' },
    { id: 'c', name: 'c', parentId: '' },
    { id: 'd', name: 'd', parentId: 'c' },
    { id: 'e', name: 'e', parentId: 'd' },
    { id: 'f', name: 'f', parentId: 'a' },
    { id: 'g', name: 'g', parentId: 'e' }
];

const map_group = (arr, build_key) =>
  arr.reduce(
    (acc, val) => {
      const key = val[build_key];

      let arr = acc.get(key);
      if(!arr) acc.set(key, arr = []);

      arr.push(val);

      return acc;
    },
    new Map()
  );

const walk = (map, start_id = 'c') => {
  let res = [];
  let queue = [start_id];
  
  while(queue.length > 0) {
    let current = queue.shift();
    res.push(current);
    
    let children = map.get(current);
    if(children)
      queue.push(...children.map((c) => c.id));
  }
  
  return res;
};

console.log(walk( map_group(data, 'parentId') ));
```

When I've actually had this kind of data structure in the past I've had a setup phase where I don't really care that much about speed and a use phase where I've wanted to respond to user input or been looping through a large percentage of the data, in which case I've tended to index by id and then taken a pass through to record the children ids on the data structure. Sometimes I've pre-computed the descendents in the setup phase too. Already knowing the answer is pretty efficient. :)

I've no idea whether the timings in the following are useful, but maybe you can try with your real data:

```js
const index = (data) => data.reduce((a, v) => a.set(v.id, v), new Map());

const build_descendent_ids_for_entry = (entry, indexed_data) => {
  entry.descendent_ids = [...entry.children_ids];
  
  entry.children_ids.forEach((child_id) => {
    entry.descendent_ids.push(
      ...get_descendent_ids_for_entry(
        indexed_data.get(child_id),
        indexed_data
      )
    );
  });
};

const get_descendent_ids_for_entry = (entry, indexed_data) => {
  if(entry.descendent_ids) return entry.descendent_ids;
  
  build_descendent_ids_for_entry(entry, indexed_data);
  
  return entry.descendent_ids;
};

const append_children_ids = (data, indexed_data) => {
  data.forEach((entry) => {
    entry.children_ids ??= [];
    
    const parent = indexed_data.get(entry.parentId);
    
    if(parent) {
      parent.children_ids ??= [];
      parent.children_ids.push(entry.id);
    }
  });
};

const append_children_and_descendent_ids = (data, indexed_data) => {
  append_children_ids(data, indexed_data);
  
  data
    .filter((entry) => entry.parentId === '')
    .forEach((entry) => {
      get_descendent_ids_for_entry(entry, indexed_data);
    });
};

const get_entry_and_descendent_ids = (indexed_data, id) => {
  const entry = indexed_data.get(id);
  
  return [entry.id, ...entry.descendent_ids];
};

const do_it = () => {
  const data = [
    { id: 'a', name: 'a', parentId: '' },
    { id: 'b', name: 'b', parentId: 'c' },
    { id: 'c', name: 'c', parentId: '' },
    { id: 'd', name: 'd', parentId: 'c' },
    { id: 'e', name: 'e', parentId: 'd' },
    { id: 'f', name: 'f', parentId: 'a' },
    { id: 'g', name: 'g', parentId: 'e' },
  ];
  const indexed_data = index(data);
  append_children_and_descendent_ids(data, indexed_data);

  return get_entry_and_descendent_ids(indexed_data, 'c');
};

console.log( ...do_it() );

const time_it = (iter = 10000) => {
  const t0 = performance.now();
  
  for(let i = 0; i < iter; i++)
    do_it();
  
  console.log('time', (performance.now() - t0) / iter);
};

const time_it_pre_build = (iter = 10000) => {
  const data = [
    { id: 'a', name: 'a', parentId: '' },
    { id: 'b', name: 'b', parentId: 'c' },
    { id: 'c', name: 'c', parentId: '' },
    { id: 'd', name: 'd', parentId: 'c' },
    { id: 'e', name: 'e', parentId: 'd' },
    { id: 'f', name: 'f', parentId: 'a' },
    { id: 'g', name: 'g', parentId: 'e' },
  ];
  const indexed_data = index(data);
  append_children_and_descendent_ids(data, indexed_data);
  
  const t0 = performance.now();
  
  for(let i = 0; i < iter; i++)
    get_entry_and_descendent_ids(indexed_data, 'c');
  
  console.log('time for pre build', (performance.now() - t0) / iter);
};

time_it();
time_it_pre_build();
```